# Doxygen edit formatting of section

Tags: javascript, html, doxygen

i have a little question about formatting the HTML-Output dynamically in Doxygen.

We are using Doxygen for the documentation of our C source codes. There are comments which are generated automatically by a CVS tool. 
For displaying these comments i created a section tag via ALIASES like "mksrevisionlist=\section mks_revisionlist MKS File Revision List". An example of these comments is below:

- Revision 1.15 2017/04/27 12:40:58CEST xxx xxx (xxxx)  *
- Added revision tags for Doxygen *
- Revision 1.14 2017/04/26 10:05:29CEST xxx xxx (xxxx)  *
- Added documentation *

This works well but now the problem is that the linebreaks of the comments are not transferred on the HTML output. 
It looks like on the screen:
[doxygen_htmlOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYM9T.png)

The Input looks like:

```
    /*******************************************************************************
 * @mksrevisionlist
 * $Log: feature/50_Src/ $ 
 * Revision 1.15 2017/04/27 12:40:58CEST xx (xxx)  *
 * Added revision tags for Doxygen *
 * Revision 1.14 2017/04/26 10:05:29CEST xx (xxx)  *
 * Added documentation * 
 * Revision 1.13 2017/04/24 14:33:52CEST xx (xxx)  *
 * Doxygen Support *
 * Revision 1.12 2017/04/21 16:14:11CEST xx (xxx)  *
 * Comment Maintenance *
 * Revision 1.11 2017/04/21 15:36:53CEST xx (xxx)  *
 * Removed includes of C*
 * Revision 1.10 2017/03/16 13:38:32CET xx (xxx)  *
 * Signal renaming: msp: out signals are now called *
 * Revision 1.9 2017/03/08 15:03:11CET xx (xxx)  *
 * Member moved from feature/50_ in project  in project  *
 * Revision 1.8 2017/02/15 11:31:26CET xx (xxx)  *
 * Updated comments about straight routing of  and  *
 * Revision 1.7 2017/01/27 17:15:03CET xx (xxx)  *
 * Removal of legacy code Step 3) *
 * Revision 1.6 2016/12/02 14:54:18CET xx (xxx)  *
 * Member moved from 50_Src/BRK/ in project  in project . *
 * Revision 1.5 2016/11/30 14:53:38CET xx (xxx)  *
 * Replaced  with . *
 * Removed  (P). *
 * Revision 1.4 2016/11/30 13:23:50CET xx (xxx)  *
 * Member moved from BRK/ in project  in project . *
 * Revision 1.3 2016/09/15 15:04:13CEST xx (xxx)  *
 * Include Cin addition to C *
 * Revision 1.2 2016/08/10 16:34:24MESZ xx (xxx)  *
 * Clean up version log information and change souce in comments to MISRA style *
 * Revision 1.1 2016/07/06 16:39:08MESZ xx (xxx)  *
 * Initial revision *
 * Member added to project  *
 *******************************************************************************/
```

The resulting HTML-Output is:

```html
<dl class="section rcs"><dt>Date</dt><dd>2017/04/27 12:40:58CEST </dd></dl>
<h1><a class="anchor" id="mks_revision"></a>
MKS File Revision</h1>
<dl class="section rcs"><dt>Revision</dt><dd>1.15 </dd></dl>
<h1><a class="anchor" id="mks_revisionlist"></a>
MKS File Revision List</h1>
<dl class="section rcs"><dt>Log</dt><dd><a class="el" href="msp___p_brake_8c.html" title="Park brake unit. ">feature/50_Src/brake/msp_PBrake.c</a> </dd></dl>
<p>Revision 1.15 2017/04/27 12:40:58CEST xx (xxx) * Added revision tags for Doxygen * Revision 1.14 2017/04/26 10:05:29CEST xx (xxx) * Added documentation * Revision 1.13 2017/04/24 14:33:52CEST xx (xxx) * Doxygen Support * Revision 1.12 2017/04/21 16:14:11CEST xx (xxx) * Comment Maintenance * Revision 1.11 2017/04/21 15:36:53CEST xxx (xxx) * Removed includes of C* Revision 1.10 2017/03/16 13:38:32CET xx (xxx) * Signal renaming: m are now called * Revision 1.9 2017/03/08 15:03:11CET xx (xxx) * Member moved from feature/50_Sr/xx in project  to <a class="el" href="xx.html" title="Park brake unit. "></a> in project . * Revision 1.8 2017/02/15 11:31:26CET xx (xxx) * Updated comments about straight routing of and  * Revision 1.7 2017/01/27 17:15:03CET xx (xxx) * Removal of legacy code Step 3) * Revision 1.6 2016/12/02 14:54:18CET xx (xxx) * Member moved from 50_Src/xx in project * Revision 1.5 2016/11/30 14:53:38CET xx (xxx) * Replaced  with . * Removed . * Revision 1.4 2016/11/30 13:23:50CET xx (xxx) * Member moved from BRK/xx in project  * Revision 1.3 2016/09/15 15:04:13CEST xx (xxx) * Include CDI_MSP.h in addition to CDI_CDI.h * Revision 1.2 2016/08/10 16:34:24MESZ xx (xxx) * Clean up version log information and change souce in comments to MISRA style * Revision 1.1 2016/07/06 16:39:08MESZ xx (xxx) * Initial revision * Member added to project  * </p>
```

We are using Doxygen Version 1.8.13.

Is there a way to format the section without manipulating the comments?

I tried it with JavaScript but it doesn't work.

Maybe someone had the sam problem in the past and found a solution for it.

Thanks and greets,
onur

Comment: Please incorporate an example of the input, and also the result and no links (people a allergic to links and they might vanish leaving the post useless) also specify the used doxygen version.

Comment: Hi, first thanks for your advices. I can't add images to the post just the links of the images. But i will try again.

Comment: If the revision history is already part of the source code, you could just enclose them with `\verbatim` and `\endverbatim` Doxygen commands or with `<pre> </pre>` HTML tags. Check out your CVS Tool and see if you can use a customized template that would include the commands/HTML tags and even your section alias.

Comment: Hello Frelling, thanks that works very well.